# php RecursiveDirectoryIterator directory removing issue

Tags: php

trying to remove empty folders using directory iterator,
however it always comes up with error: Access is denied (code: 5) after directory was removed.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($images_path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    try {

        echo "Removing empty folders...\n";

        foreach ($objects as $object) {

            if ($object->isDir()) {
                echo $object->getRealPath()."\n";
                $isDirEmpty = new FilesystemIterator($object->getRealPath());
                if (!$isDirEmpty->valid()){
                    echo $object->getFilename() . " - directory removed\n";
                    $path = $object->getRealPath();
                    rmdir($path);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Which line?  I'd comment out the catch for debugging...

Comment: please state line where error is happening?

Comment: error happens @ foreach line (function: getChildren)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory iterator still "remembers" that the folder exists and so tries to read its content. But as you deleted it, the iterator fails.

To fix this you can put empty folders paths into an array and then delete them after the main loop has finished.

```
$empty_dirs = [];
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($images_path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
try {

    echo "Removing empty folders...\n";

    foreach ($objects as $object) {

        if ($object->isDir()) {
            echo $object->getRealPath()."\n";
            $isDirEmpty = new FilesystemIterator($object->getRealPath());
            if (!$isDirEmpty->valid()){
                echo $object->getFilename() . " - directory removed\n";
                $path = $object->getRealPath();
                //rmdir($path);
                $empty_dirs[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

foreach ($empty_dirs as $path)
{
    rmdir($path);
}
```

---

One more way, without the array:

```
$empty_dir = null;
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($images_path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
try {

    echo "Removing empty folders...\n";

    foreach ($objects as $object) {

        if ($object->isDir()) {
            echo $object->getRealPath()."\n";
            $isDirEmpty = new FilesystemIterator($object->getRealPath());
            if (!$isDirEmpty->valid()){
                echo $object->getFilename() . " - directory removed\n";
                $path = $object->getRealPath();
                if ($empty_dir !== null)
                    rmdir($empty_dir);
                $empty_dir = $path;
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if (!is_null($empty_dir))
    rmdir($empty_dir);
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution.
Interesting that this happens with directories only, files can be removed without issues.

Comment: If you're worried that the array will grow too much, you actually can delete the previous empty folder when you find the next one or when the iterator gives you the next. I'll update the answer to explain what I mean.